# Why does Internet Explorer simply stop parsing in the middle of my CSS?

Tags: html, css

I help manage a website for a local ACM student chapter, http://acm.cs.uakron.edu/.

For some reason, Internet Explorer simply refuses to parse the majority of the CSS. Every other browser I know of handles it just fine, but why does IE7+ stop?

Comment: Define "refuses to parse" and include the CSS (or a convenience link to it) to get (better) answers.

Comment: Which CSS file are you talking about? There's about three dozen stylesheets on the page that you linked to.

Comment: It appears there are 35 separate CSS files included on that page (which is rather horrifying, by the way - consider a compile stage that combines them). Are you having problems with one in particular? Have you made certain there are no syntax errors in the file?

Comment: More information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211991/does-ie-8-have-a-limit-on-number-of-stylesheets-per-page

Answer (score 10):

The comments say you have 35 CSS files. That in itself, in addition to just being a lot of requests, is enough to be a showstopper for IE.

According to [Microsoft Knowledge Base Article 262161](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262161),

> All style tags after the first 31 style tags are not applied.

This [applies to](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262161#appliesto) all versions of IE so far, including the IE9 beta. Ouch. Time to merge those stylesheets into one file.

When handling big complex CSS projects like that, I usually recommend using a CSS pre-processor like [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/), and turning those smaller stylesheets into includes pulled into the larger stylesheet that is fed to the browser. Almost everyone has a different solution to this particular issue, though.

Comment: It's amazing how IE can impose such arbitrary limits in the most unsuspecting of places.

Comment: To be honest, if you have to make 35 different HTTP requests just for one page's CSS you _are_ doing it wrong.

Comment: @badp: Yeah, it's not a great thing for a website to be doing, but it's also odd for a browser to simply refuse to handle something and not even error out.

Answer (score 4):

Internet Explorer can not parse any more than 31 CSS files wether embedded or not. Even if you use the [@import](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cssmerge/) css syntax IE will ignore everything after 31 files! *How crap is that?*

try http://sourceforge.net/projects/cssmerge/