# Why does Internet Explorer not parse my CSS?

Tags: html, css

In my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3918330/why-does-internet-explorer-simply-stop-parsing-in-the-middle-of-my-css) (asked before I registered), I asked why my ACM chapter's site doesn't get all the way through IE's CSS parser. Got an answer, but after turning on Drupal's CSS caching which merges all CSS into one file, absolutely no CSS is handled. What gives? The CSS validator says there's a few bugs but none of them look like they'd be absolutely fatal.

Comment: According to IE8's developer toolbar, all three style sheets seem to get parsed, but probably only partly (there are very few rules that seem to apply)

Comment: You might also want to email the team asking for an account merge. Use the **contact us** link at the bottom, or flag your previous question for mod attention.

Answer (score 0):

Running your CSS through a validator shows you have heaps of errors, you might want to fix those.

http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=http%3A%2F%2Facm.cs.uakron.edu%2Fsites%2Fdefault%2Ffiles%2Fcss%2Fcss_753a2c990c630e98f7da739ed5ca7c79.css

Comment: None of them seems to be responsible for IE not parsing it at all, though.

Comment: Well it seems theres two lots of css files. The one in the header. Then the bottom of the page has: jQuery.extend(Drupal.settings, { "CToolsAJAX": { *loads css files* Maybe these are not being loaded, I don't have firefox or anything to test with other than IE. But fiddler shows no requests for those files.

Comment: Ahh theres a LOT wrong with that CSS. Theres CSS with upper casing, not the HTML is lower cased. Class names with numbers in them (should avoid using numbers in CSS at all times), properties with no values. Browser hacks.