# is there an ie7 styles limit?

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

ive been having trouble with ie7 for the past hour and it seems it ignores some styles i have at a certain point.

I was baffled at first because i had this style:

```
#results-main {
  min-height: 440px;
  color: black;
}
```

this totally works in fireox etc but then ie7 was being a bitch about it and didn't render any styles for results-main. I added it in a separate ie.css with a conditional for ie7 and it worked. I investigated more into this because i knew i already had that style(so why duplicate it in ie.css?) and i was baffled at what i found out. Apparently, ie ignores my styles from line 600+.

I know that ie has a limit on imported styles(32 stylesheets) so i squished all my styles in one. I also know ie's 300+kb file size limit for css, and i think im just at 19kb. So what is the deal with IE7 ignoring my styles at a certain point?

I further tested this by moving my results-main upwards. now they are at line 127 and it totally works for ie now. So what IS the deal with this?!

I included a pastie of my css here:

http://pastie.org/1635871

anything from #results-main downwards, will not render in IE7. If I switch results-main styles with say, #nav styles, results-main will show up in IE7 while #nav styles won't.

Comment: Have you validated the CSS to see whether there is a syntax problem somewhere?

Comment: This may be of interest, but the limits are sufficiently high, so that almost no pages hit them: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211991/does-ie-8-have-a-limit-on-number-of-stylesheets-per-page

Answer (score 2):

Most likely there's a syntax error in your stylesheet. All browsers I know of will work easily beyond 600 lines of CSS

Comment: i've actually tried "reshuffling" my styles and IE7 breaks at a certain point(not lines...but the number of styles itself). i tried compressing my css and it still happens

Answer (score 1):

IE 6,7 and 8 have some limitations for 31(2^5-1) stylesheets per page.

Take a look at [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/iewebdevelopment/thread/ad1b6e88-bbfa-4cc4-9e95-3889b82a7c1d) & also [here](http://john.albin.net/ie-css-limits/993-style-test.html)

This problem has existed for about 3 years, and microsoft did not answer.