# Internet Explorer 6 CSS loading issues

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, loading

I saw some of the sections related to IE issues in our stackoverflow website but still my question awaits.

In my local server I am running an application which is loading JS and CSS files perfectly and working fine in IE7+ and Firefox. The problem is with IE6.

If running in IE6, able to load small amount of data but not if large data.

Able to find that the complete problem causes with CSS but don't know where I am going wrong in CSS.

I tested my application with w3c validator, it shows some minor errors which can be ignored and everything looks good.

Even using IE Fixes CSS.

Could any one please provide me some ideas, like is there any css debug for IE6.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Oh boy, IE6 issues again. :-( Why do people still insist on supporting IE6??? As a developer, if someone asks you to write a web site, and they specify IE6 support as a requirment, tell them it'll double the development cost.

Comment: ahh, These all discussion are already done and then I started to fix.

Comment: Have you checked sites like quirksmode.org and caniuse.com to ensure that all the features you're using are supported by IE6?

Comment: Hi Guys, I solved this.. ironically a div position relative causes to hang in IE6. Thanks all, for the suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you are generating a `<style>` element for every *data row*? This is common (although I don't like it) when you don't have access to the `<head>` element or cannot concatenate rules into a single `<style>` element.

If so, do you have more than 31 `<style>` elements? IE has a limit on the number of stylesheets, so you might be seeing that problem.

There are a lot of blog posts (and SO question) on this. Here are some of the better ones I could find:

[Does IE 8 have a limit on number of stylesheets per page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211991/does-ie-8-have-a-limit-on-number-of-stylesheets-per-page), [Stylesheets Not Loading? 31 Reasons to Hate Internet Explorer](http://john.albin.net/css/ie-stylesheets-not-loading) and [Internet Explorer CSS limits](http://blogs.telerik.com/blogs/posts/10-05-03/internet_explorer_css_limits.aspx).

Comment: Thanks andy, This gives me some study and I solved by my way but this is helpful

Answer (score 2):

The [Internet explorer developer toolbar](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=95e06cbe-4940-4218-b75d-b8856fced535) may go somewhere to help you. It's extremely useful, although not as good as other browser alternatives. It can be installed on IE6. To access it once installed it's in the "convenient" place of view-->toolbars

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [FirebugLite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) (for IE6), and installing [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com).