# Does IE9 have a file size limit for CSS?

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9, stylesheet

I'm using Drupal and I notice that if I have my CSS files aggregated that the CSS doesn't always work correctly. I know there is a [problem in IE7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/29994/drupal-aggregate-css-crashes-ie7) but is there a limit to a CSS file size in IE9?

Comment: This is a vague question. What else can you tell us?

Comment: It seems that somebody else has had the same problem, please check  http://stackoverflow.com/a/3212065/795876

Comment: @fsehat thanks for the link, that didn't come up in my previous searches unfortunately

Answer (score 103, accepted):

There are 3 limits:

- a sheet may contain up to 4095 selectors, see
  http://demos.telerik.com/testcases/4095issues.html
- a sheet may @import up to 31 sheets, see http://demos.telerik.com/testcases/BrokenTheme.aspx
- @import nesting supports up to 4 levels deep

Microsoft support/MSDN reference links:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/262161

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/05/14/internet-explorer-stylesheet-rule-selector-import-sheet-limit-maximum.aspx

Comment: To notice, IE10 doesn't have this limit (including when in IE7-8-9 modes)

Comment: there's a ~288kb file max too. Info: http://joshua.perina.com/africa/gambia/fajara/post/internet-explorer-css-file-size-limit

Comment: @RaphaelDDL I don't think that link should be taken at face value. I regularly see larger files. The link author probably hit the selector limit.

Comment: @noah I've had cases files around that size have failed while still being below the other limits.  Splitting into multiple files fixed the problem so it's worth checking out.

Comment: In my testing of IE9 I found the MAX SIZE to be 278kb

Comment: I've seen other people mention the 278kb limit as well 
https://gist.github.com/psebborn/1885511#comment-1383451

Comment: I'm on the low side, but I'm getting the behaviour at 270KB

Comment: For a silly guess, I'm going to say anything greater than 256 (the 8th power of two) might be the limit. If the file was loaded into a single byte field, that might be the issue. The next size up is 1024.. I haven't seen anything there.

Comment: I could not find any evidence for a 288KB limit. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49683077/is-there-a-css-file-size-limit-in-ie9/49784811#49784811