# What's the size limit of css file for Internet Explorer?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Does IE9 have a file size limit for CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11080560/does-ie9-have-a-file-size-limit-for-css)

I encountered a problem where in IE9 it appeared as if some parts of my CSS style was not loading. I tracked the problem and found my css file exceed the limit size. I want to ask what's the limit size of css file for IE, and is it the same among IE6,IE7,IE8 and IE9.

Comment: What's more interesting is there are answers like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211991/does-ie-8-have-a-limit-on-number-of-stylesheets-per-page/3212065#3212065) demonstrating that there is even a cap on the amount of CSS files you can include.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maximum number of possible selectors in a CSS file - 4095

http://demos.telerik.com/testcases/4095issues.html

31 stylesheets per file

http://demos.telerik.com/testcases/BrokenTheme.aspx

Comment: Looks a lot like [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11080560/does-ie9-have-a-file-size-limit-for-css).