# CSS file loads only half selectors

Tags: css, asp.net

My asp.net website uses one CSS file with two groups of selectors ".Tab" and ".TabLower". On my development machine the CSS loads with all selectors and is applied correctly, when I deploy the website to production server (IIS 7) only the first selector ".Tab" is loaded if I inspect the page.

What is the cause of this issue?

[image: Side-by-side image]

CSS file

```
/* ############################################
Tab - default tab
############################################### */
/*Body*/
.Tab .ajax__tab_body
{
    border: 5px solid #B6C9D4;
    padding: 15px;
}
/*Tab Active*/
.Tab .ajax__tab_active .ajax__tab_tab
{
    color: #000000;
    padding: 7px;
    background-color: #B6C9D4;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.Tab .ajax__tab_active .ajax__tab_inner
{
    background-color: #B6C9D4;
    padding: 7px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
    border-left: 2px solid #ffffff;
    border-right: 2px solid #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #B6C9D4;
}
/*Tab Inactive*/
.Tab .ajax__tab_tab
{
    color: #666666;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    padding: 7px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.Tab .ajax__tab_inner
{
    color: #666666;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    padding: 7px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
    border-left: 2px solid #ffffff;
    border-right: 2px solid #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
}

/* ############################################
TabLower
############################################### */

/*Body*/
.TabLower .ajax__tab_body
{
    border: 5px solid #B6C9D4;
    padding: 15px;
}
/*Tab Active*/
.TabLower .ajax__tab_active .ajax__tab_tab
{
    color: #000000;
    padding: 4px;
    background-color: #B6C9D4;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.TabLower .ajax__tab_active .ajax__tab_inner
{
    background-color: #B6C9D4;
    padding: 4px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
    border-left: 2px solid #ffffff;
    border-right: 2px solid #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #B6C9D4;
}

/*Tab Inactive*/
.TabLower .ajax__tab_tab
{
    color: #666666;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    padding: 4px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.TabLower .ajax__tab_inner
{
    color: #666666;
    background-color: #F2F2F2;
    padding: 4px;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
    border-left: 2px solid #ffffff;
    border-right: 2px solid #ffffff;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Are you getting any error in browser error console?

Comment: Interesting, yes I do get an error on prod server "HTML1113: Document mode restart from IE7 Standards to IE9 Standards", I googled a bit and SO recommends putting "<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />" which I already have in cluded in my master page.

Comment: Is this happening in all browser or only in IE 9?

Comment: Sadly I am limited to IE9, some users have IE10 or IE11 but only IE (client restriction...), so yes the error is in IE (9 in my case) but this is all I can test with.

Comment: please refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11080560/does-ie9-have-a-file-size-limit-for-css

Comment: I'm not sure how but it works now, what I did was put <!DOCTYPE html> at the very first line in webpage and manually turned Compatibility mode off, now it works. But the strange thing is if I put <!DOCTYPE html> back to second line and turn Compatibility back on it still works!? I'll try with some users on their PC's and see what gives.