# controlling Visual Studio css/js optimization when debugging

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

We have a large project with a large number of css files.  I use MS bundling which combines everything into a single file in production.  Some might argue we have too many css files, but  having a file for each relevant section helps to compartmentalize and organize everything.

When we test with IE8, we run into the [31 file css file limitation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211991/does-ie-8-have-a-limit-on-number-of-stylesheets-per-page).  We can get around this by running in Release mode (which bundles all the css), but then the JS is bundled as well, and we can't debug.

Is there a way to make our CSS bundle, but not the JS?

Comment: I think this might work for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11944745/asp-net-bundles-how-to-disable-minification#11956652